# How to composite watermark with Perlmagick?

Tags: perl, imagemagick, perlmagick

I wrote a script to watermark images. On command line adding watermark works fine:

```
composite -dissolve 5% -gravity South watermark.png original.jpg new.jpg
```

Now when I tried to use Perlmagick for watermarking, the composite part does not change anything:

```
my $i = new Image::Magick;
my $watermark = $i->Read( "watermark.png" );

my $i2 = new Image::Magick;
my $p = $i->Read( "original.jpg" );

$i->Set( Gravity => 'Center' );
$i->Resize( geometry => "600x600" );
$i->Composite( image=>$watermark, compose=>"Dissolve", opacity=>5, gravity=>"South" );

$i->Write( 'jpg:temp_file' );
```

Such script resizes image, but does not watermark it.

Problem seems to be in the way I provide dissolving degree. On command line I can add percentage to dissolve-attribute, but in API version dissolve is itself attribute. I tried with opacity, but this seems not the right way too.

What is the right way to use dissolve in Perlmagick?

Edit:
Images I use

[original](https://pasteboard.co/tX03hVyT7vDj.jpg)

[watermark](https://pasteboard.co/2YgpfENHg8Y7.png)

[new](https://pasteboard.co/j4OGaamO0Wml.jpg) (result of command `composite -dissolve 5% -gravity South watermark.png original.jpg new.jpg`)

Comment: *"Problem seems to be in the way I provide dissolving degree."* : There is an example here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/25e3a4f3845f59536d19aba0ac0580aa6715147f/PerlMagick/demo/compose-specials.pl#L120 using `args => 50` to provide dissolve arguments

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks for the link. Still it does not work, `args` seems to work like on/off switch instead of gradual increase/decrease. Given example there I can't see the difference having `args` 50 or 50x50 or completely different values.

Comment: Can you upload the test images somewhere? Then we could try experimenting with them.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Added links to images. Thank you for looking into problem

Comment: Added ticket: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/6738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Image::Magick;

my $watermark = Image::Magick->new();
{
    my $error = $watermark->Read( "watermark.png" );
    die "Cannot read watermark.png: $error" if $error;
}
my $original = Image::Magick->new();
{
    my $error = $original->Read( "original.jpg" );
    die "Cannot read original.jpg: $error" if $error;
}

#$watermark->Set( Gravity => 'Center' );
#$watermark->Resize( geometry => "600x600" );
{
    my $error = $original->Composite(
        image=>$watermark,
        compose=>"dissolve",
    #    args => "90",
        opacity=>"2%",
        gravity=>"South"
    );
    die "Cannot do composite: $error" if $error;
}    
{
    my $error = $original->Write( 'new.jpg' );
    die "Cannot write new.jpg: $error" if $error;
}
say "Done.";
```

It gives me:

[image]

So you can see the watermark has been composed into the original. So maybe the `opacity` parameter can be used like this?

Comment: The bottom part of the image seems promising, but why the upper part is black now?

Comment: Thank you for confirming that problem relies in software.